# What were the reasons for adding "ôm" at end in Subrahmanyôm?

Tags: indra, kartikeya

In this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29195/3869) it was explained the meaning of Subrahmanya as **"su—brahmaṇya very kind or dear to Brāhmans"**.

In the [Subrahmanya litany](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe26/sbe2614.htm), it was mentioned as **Subrahmanyôm** (3:3:4:17 of Satapatha Brahmana), while referring to Indra.

My question is as to why ***ôm***  was  added at the end of Subrahmanya?