# Which Gods besides Vishnu have been declared as Supreme and/or Brahman in the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, brahman

Vishnu,Narayana,Vasudeva,Janardana and Krishna have been declared supreme many times in Mahabharata.

Which other Gods have also been declared as supreme, the origin of everything or Brahman in the Mahabharata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Garuda (by Devas - Adi Parva: Chapter 23)
- Indra (by Kadru - Adi Parva: Chapter 26)
- Surya (by Vashistha - Adi Parva: Chapter 172)
- Agni (by Sage Mandalala - Adi Parva: Chapter 228, Birds - Adi Parva: Chapter 231)
- Kartikeya ([Do any scripture portrays Lord Kartikeya (Murugan) to be the Supreme God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/do-any-scripture-portrays-lord-kartikeya-murugan-to-be-the-supreme-god/29290#29290))
- Shiva/Rudra (by Upamanyu - Anushashan Parva: Chapter 17)

Comment: also, Shiva/Rudra in Drona parva

Comment: Wow!!!!!!!!!!!  Hinduism is self-similar - each genuine major scripture is a microcosm of the whole of Hinduism. @YDS

Answer (score 2):

Here are two examples.

> The Supreme Spirit hath three condition, In the form of Brahma, he is
> the Creator, and in the form of Vishnu he is the Preserver, and in his
> form as Rudra, he is the Destroyer of the Universe.

**Mahabharata Vana Parva Section CCLXX**

> Mahadeva is eternal Brahman.

**Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section XVII**