# How to progress spiritually without discrimination?

Tags: spiritual-level, bhakti, gunas

When I first make some progress in spiritual life, I have to develop some discrimination for certain things like food, friends, activities, etc...

But I soon realized that I'm creating my very own bubble cage. I started to discriminate so that I will not fall into the temptations to go back.
But as soon as I don't discriminate: e.g. my relatives that eat meat, I feel that I'm slowly falling in *rajas/tamas* guna.
And I'm starting to get exhausted because there is so much influence in this world, its like swimming in the river but in the wrong directon. I know that we are all God's particles, but still I'm just a man with this level of awareness...

How to progress in spiritual life, so that I can live in *sAtvic* way without discriminating anything?

Comment: It's a wrong notion that eating meat is *Rajas* / *Tamas*. Eating too tasty things e.g salty, spicy, hot etc. is *Rajas*; while eating food of bad taste, smelly & and too old (usually packed) food is *Tamas*. I am a pure veg, but in no way I condemn meat eaters. Above things also apply only when you have a choice to make. Of course there are other non health related issues with meat, but entirely different from your perception. If you can understand [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10744/1049), (see contents not topic) then may be I post an answer with that as base argument.

Comment: Good question. What you have to understand is this: Everyone has a role in this Universe. Think about a giant movie. There is a hero, there is a heroine, there is a villain, there is a comedian, there is a dancer, there is a singer, there is a saint, so on. God (Your True Self) is the director. Just believe that you are playing your role (as a Yogi) and your relatives are playing their roles (as Regulars). That's it. Everyone is part and parcel of this world. WIth this attitude, soon you will develop Ekatma Bhava (Oneness of Jivas) and you will develop Prema (Supreme Love) towards all.

Comment: To progress, find your guru.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda has the correct answer.Without a Guru you can't progress even an inch.Your Guru can only teach you how to discriminate and what to discriminate.You can't decide that on your own.

Comment: And since thoughts of this nature are coming to your mind it only indicates that you are bound to progress.Only what is needed for you is a SatGuru who will guide you and make the path of your progress free of obstacles.All the best bro :)

Comment: * for the time being you can pray to Lord Dakshinamuthy by chanting this sloka:"Nidhaaye Sarva Vidyaanaam,Bhisaje sarva Roginaam,Gurave Sarva Lokaanaam Dakshina Murtaye Namaha." Being the Guru of the entire universe he will certainly guide you in finding your personal Guru. :)

Comment: @iammilind , Krishna specifically states in [gita ch.17](http://asitis.com/17/) that very spicy foods and old food give rise to rajas/tamas qualities

Comment: To give you a short answer I would just say that to progress in the spiritual life you always must to know what you are doing and what decisions to make, so you always have to discriminate. Btw, if you have many practical questions in your life such as "What should I do about this ... and that ...?", etc, then this Hi SE website is not quite a proper place to ask those Qs, but you should find some people who live spiritual life and ask them those questions to guide you. It's not quite necessary to have a guru. ...

Comment: ... What hindu traditions you are interested in? Think about that and find their people who can offer you some practical guidance.

Comment: Besides looking for a guru, remember that there are two legs on which spiritual progress happens- faith(shraddha) and perseverence (saburi as stated by Sai baba). Keep persevering along the path and problems will get resolved by themselves. Vimarsa(introspection+cogitation) and prakasa(enlightenment) are the two feet of the guru.(guru paduka) and translate to continual (and sometimes non-monotonic) spiritual progress. Let me know if you want me to elaborate. God bless.

Comment: Don't run away from things and don't fall in love with them either. Be neutral, be the spectator

Comment: @Sai Your answere helped me to find a way, I think this is the right way. Be actor and play in this world, but be aware that you are actor in movie. Thank you my firend!

Comment: @Sai, why don't you formalize your comment as an answer for the record? It will help more people like the OP. BTW, if possible then you may elaborate in your answer about: "Why *Prema* (supreme love) has to be or should be developed?". Personally I din't get that part. :-)

Comment: @iammilind Good point. Supreme Love is another name for Eternal Bliss, the end goal of all spirituality. Love yourself as you are, and you will see that you love others the way they are. You will be completely detached. The Jnanis try to attain Supreme Love by realizing that the world is Unreal, only 'I' is real. Therefore they try to be always happy with themselves, no matter what (because everything is unreal after all). This is Loving Yourself. The Bhaktas try to attain Supreme Love by giving an object of worship. They say that this svarupa (or form) is worthy of all auspicious qualities.

Comment: @iammilind (Continued...) Therefore they believe that the object of life is to serve this Being (Ishvara). As they serve, they realize that Ishvara is like a Loving Father or a Loving Mother. Ishvara has no expectations and has no desires. Ishvara is the embodiment of sacrifice. By Loving Ishvara, they are accepting His Grace. They say 'I have surrendered to God, therefore I am saved'. In other words, they are simply accepting Ishvara's Love for them and they are thereby accepting themselves as deserving of Ishvara's protection. Similarly for Karma Yogis. All the best friend! :)

Answer (score 9):

Krishna says in the *Gita* (IV. 34.) Swami Nikhilananda translator:

> Learn it by prostration, by inquiry and by service. The wise, who have seen the Truth, will teach you that Knowledge.

And the *Chandogya Upanishad* (IV. ix. 3.) Swami Nikhilananda translator:

> Only the knowledge that is learnt from a teacher leads to the Highest Good.

And again in *Chandogya Upanishad* (VI. xiv. 2.):

> He who meets with a teacher to instruct him obtains true knowledge.

Find your guru.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question you put out there.. I think that's very true of many novice followers of this "Sanatan Dharma" lifestyle.

One thing I understand at this point is - it should come natural to you. There must not be the great inside resistance. Until you find that "Sahaj" path/style that progresses towards that Higher Abode... keep searching/fumbling into your inside inventory.

Good answers so far.

*~~~ This is a view of what I understood from various sources including own life experiences, there may be better explanation/justification.*