# How exactly Moksha is considered eternal?

Tags: moksha

Where will over soul be in moksha state??What happens in complete enlightened state??.People usually say enlightment is the goal or moksha is complete enlighment but none has a complete answer instead people talk in air.Please answer my question i am tensed.And how can it be enlightment if moksha is temporary..see this [Is Moksha a permanent state?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/is-moksha-a-permanent-state).

Comment: Because these cant be talked with words definitely as it is definitely highest stage to be experienced. Because you cant express it in words properly that stage!

Comment: Amazing answer @Akshay

Comment: I have to say in words, its eternal stillness. No mind, no body = Kaivalya Moksha! 5 types of Mokshas are there!!! To put in simple words, freedom from process of birth, death, old age disease!!! is Moksha... because you are beyond these 4 process of life! Also personally I dont go with view of Moksha is temporary as Krishna says in Gita, he never takes birth again!

Comment: My gosh OPs English is terrible!

Comment: @Wikash_hindu When are you going to give me your address so I can send Hanuman to you?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu what were u not able to understand?

Comment: Nothing happens in moksha. Moksha is oneness with Brahman. All is simply bliss. For something to 'happen', it must occur within time and space, as 'happen' implies change occurring in time. Nothing happens, there is no time, It simply 'is'. Eternal Infinite Bliss