# Can one person after reaching Moksha be phisically still alive in the jivanloka and so on Earth? In which ways will we live our lives then?

Tags: moksha

Starting points:

This : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2582/22667 very interesting and accurate answer to a question inherent to the Moksha, rises another set of questions about Moksha inside me.
According to this: ¶
Nrishima Tapani Upanishad 2.4:

```
muktāpi lilayā vigraham kritvā tvām bhajante
- Even the liberated souls in the pastimes taking forms worship you.¶
```

So the Moksha is temporary if one consider the kalpa as the time-line but, accordingly to the whole answer to the question, it seems that more than one kind of Mukti exists.
Therefore, through this:

¶There are different types of mukti and there are different schools of thought on this also. But the most common thing of mukti is mayanivriti (liberation from maya). Once, one gets beyond maya, it can't cover him again just like darkness can never cover light. ¶

If overcoming the Maya means be in the beyondess of the substance of the wordly matter it means, also accordingly to the Bhagavad Geeta that we will overcome the interdependence with the prakrti, we will not be objects, subjects and subjugated by the Gunas.

Questions:

1.So exactly which kind of living existence our aatma will conduce into the realm of Maya, that is the worldly matter?

2.How can lokasamgraha be exercised  towards the other people by us then, as human beings?

3.In which way will we be capable of be interested to perform any activities or life styles such as grihasta or purushartas like Aartha?

4.Will we be able to live only like jivaatmas, regardless of the needs of the body, and careless of the around of us society of humans?

5.And is this the very essence of the Mukti?

6.If we will become Mrityunjaya it means that our physical body will become immortal also?

7.Will the physical body of us change too?

Comment: No. Mukti/Moksha involves shedding both sthula shareer (gross physical body which we see on earth) and sukshma shareer (fine metaphysical body - that we carry to svarga & naraka after leaving sthula shareer on earth)

Comment: So we will die and never reborn again, right @ram? Is that true also in mayanivriti? And: aren't the bodies 3?

Comment: yes only if u get moksha.. for regular life-death, there is no option other than rebirth (after a brief or extended stay in svarga or naraka). yes the 3rd "body" is spiritual (non-material) body that u get in moksha/vaikunta

Comment: Thank you @ram :)