# Can the intellect (buddhi) be equated with Ishvara?

Tags: vedanta, atma, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

Since Ishvara is the ruler of the universe, the Lord, can we say that, in our microcosm, our *buddhi* (intellect - the decision maker) is equivalent to Ishvara?

Comment: His(Isvara) shakti is mother of Buddhitattva (The Cosmic Intelligence). see this answer http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9370/3500

Comment: Yes and no. Ishvara or Saguna Brahman is beyond the Intelligence, because Ishvara is one with Brahman. however the very idea of Ishvara only exists within the realm of Intelligence. When one transcends the Intelligence (which is the subtlest form of Avidhya), then one no longer views Ishvara, one can only realize the Nirguna Brahman, also known as Brahman. All the best! Thus

Comment: That being the case, does Ishvara map into the pure knowledge of 'I Am' _prior_ to any thought or perception? After all, this particle is, necessarily, the 'ruler' of the universe because everything is inferred through it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not say buddhi is equivalent to Ishvara. This is clear from the following passages:

> The senses are great, they say. Superior to the senses is the mind,
>   and superior even to the mind is the intellect. **What is superior even
>   to the intellect is He, the Atman.**

Gita 3.42

> **Thus knowing Him who is superior even to the Buddhi**, and controlling
>   the lower self with the higher, kill that tough enemy in the form of
>   lust, O mighty-armed Arjuna.

Gita 3.43