# Why do rigveda and yajurveda contradict with each other on supremacy of rudra

Tags: shiva, vedas

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudra#Epithets_of_supreme_rule) page on wikipedia claims that vedas are contradictory, contradiction is as follows.

The verse Rig Veda 2.33.9 calls Rudra as **"The Lord or Sovereign of the Universe" (īśānādasya bhuvanasya)**.

sthirebhiraṅghaiḥ pururūpa ughro babhruḥ śukrebhiḥ pipiśehiraṇyaiḥ
īśānādasya bhuvanasya bhūrerna vā u yoṣad rudrādasuryam (RV 2.33.9)

With firm limbs, multiform, the strong, the tawny adorns himself with bright gold decorations:
The strength of Godhead never departs from Rudra, him who is Sovereign of this world, the mighty.[31]

However, Yajur Veda – Taittiriya Aranyaka (1-10-1) quotes Rudra and Brihaspati as Sons of Bhumi and Heaven.This directly conflicts with the claim of Rudra being Supreme as declared in Rigveda 2.33.9.

Since supremacy of Shriman Narayana is well established, why does vedas make such empty claims, and if claims are non empty then why are they contradictory?

Comment: Whether Vishnu or Shiva is supreme is clearly a core disagreement between the different sects of Hinduism, so I'm closing your question, since it would likely lead to too much opinion-based speculation.

Comment: But let me just say that Bhuvana means Earth, so there isn't really a contradiction between saying that someone is a Lord of the Earth and saying that he is a son of Heaven and Earth.

Comment: These are not empty claims. These are different 'school of thoughts' within Hinduism. They are not contradictory but exist in harmony with each other. You need to understand pluralism: "Hinduism is naturally pluralistic. A well-known Rig Vedic hymn says: "Truth is One, though the sages know it variously" (Ékam sat vipra bahudā vadanti). The Hindu religion has no theological difficulties in accepting degrees of truths. Hinduism emphasizes that everyone actually worships the same God, whether one knows it or not...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_pluralism#Hinduism

Comment: I don't see any contradiction at all... Yajurveda 4.5.2 clearly states "Jagatam Pataye Namaha" which means "Salutation to him who is Lord Of Universe"... It's your own perspective that Supremacy of Narayana is established in Vedas... see my answer here to know about different perspectives from Vedas... http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born/13639#13639

Comment: if supremacy of sriman narayana is established, it is certainly post-rig-vedic since narayana does not occur in rig veda.  vishnu is a minor god in rig veda his three steps depicting the movement of the sun.  there must have been a vaishnavite power-grab after rig veda.if narayana allegedly became supreme.