# Why Lord shiva is the most powerful GOD?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana

Why Lord shiva is the most powerful GOD?

Comment: The most powerful in what way?

Comment: In what way shiva is not powerful?

Comment: Let's not debate on that, please. I asked a valid question. Your "question" is unclear, lacking details, and now it's even closed a POB.

Comment: @Parth Trivedi you may be interested in my answer here : http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born/13639#13639

Comment: As i have written proof in sanskrita in my answer no need of more words.

Comment: @Parth Trivedi also see my question answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/what-names-of-lord-shiva-used-today-are-from-vedas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Mahimna Strotra](http://www.sanskrit-sanscrito.com.ar/en/shiva-mahimna-stotram-normal-translation/597)

> महेशान्नापरो देवो महिम्नो नापरा स्तुतिः।
> अघोरान्नापरो मन्त्रो नास्ति तत्त्वं गुरोः परम्॥३७॥
>
> There is no god (devaḥ) that is higher (aparaḥ) than Mahesha --an epithet of Siva meaning "great Lord"-- , there is no hymn of praise (stutiḥ) which is higher than (this) Sivamahimnaḥ stotram . There is no Mantra --a sacred word-- which is higher than Aghora --an epithet of Shiva meaning "not terrific"-- (and) there is no  principle (tattvam) that is superior to the Guru --in the sense of the fifth "kṛtya" or action of Śiva, which bestows divine Grace upon a limited being-- ||37||

Comment: this post does not answer WHY for the Question. (since its the same person who asked Q, it does not matter I guess, as it is already accepted)