# Who is the Creator of all Energy and Sources in the Universe?

Tags: shiva, krishna, puranas, brahma

Who is the creator of all Energy and Sources in the Universe?I want to know the name of the God.

Comment: Looks like you want name of Supreme Brahman. This depends on sect.  **Ekam Sat Vipra Bahudha Vadanti**, "Existence (God) is One, Sages call it/him by different Names": Rig Veda, 1-164-146.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Brahman is the both material and intellectual cause of creation in Vedanta:**

> सर्वं खल्विदं ब्रह्म तज्जलानिति शान्त उपासीत अथ खलु क्रतुमयः पुरुषो यथाक्रतुरस्मिल्लोके पुरुषो भवति तथेतः प्रेत्य भवति स क्रतुं कुर्वीतः । [Chandogya Upanishad: 3.14.1]
>
> III-xiv-1: Verily, all this universe is Brahman. **From Him do all things originate, into Him do they dissolve and by Him are they sustained.** On Him should one meditate in tranquillity. For as is one’s faith, such 
>   indeed one is; and as is one’s faith in this.

Now, if you want to personify the above 'Brahman', you may call him **Krishna/Vishnu** by quoting verses from *Bhagvad Gita,* You may call him **Shiva** by quoting verses from *Svestasvatara Upanishad.* You may call him both **Shiva and Narayana** by quoting passages from *Taittariya Aranyaka.* You may call him **Brahma** by quoting passages from *Satapatha Brahmana.* You may call him **Ganesha** by quoting *Ganapati Atharvashirsha*. You may call Brahman as **Shakti** by quoting *Devi Gita and Devi Bhagavatam* and so on...

See my [answer here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born/13639#13639) for scriptual refrences of above points.

Comment: Very good answer.