# What does the word "birth" means in Brahma's seventh birth.?

Tags: mahabharata, vishnu, brahma, rebirth, birth

Vaishampayana while narrating Hayagriva story, details how Brahma worshipped Narayana.

**The Mahabharata, Book 12.: Santi Parva.: Section CCCXLVIII.:**

In that Brahma says as follows.:

> ***As regards myself, I have sprung through thy Grace. From thee have I derived my birth. My first birth from thee, which is regarded sacred by all regenerate persons, was due to a fiat of thy Mind. My second birth in days of yore was from thy eyes. Through thy Grace, my third birth was from thy speech. My fourth birth. O puissant Lord, was from thy ears. My fifth birth, excellent in all respects, was from thy nose. O Lord, My sixth birth was, through thee, from an egg. This is my seventh birth. It has occurred, O Lord, within this Lotus, and it is meant to stimulate the intellect and desires of all the beings.***

What does "birth" here means.? Is it Brahma's birth at the start of each kalpa.? If so why only 7 births as Brahma is said to be 50+ years old.?

Comment: Please mention about the scripture with exact refrence from which this passage is taken

Comment: Even I was confused in this and asked questions related to it long back. Even if it means Mahakalpas (100 Kalpas; whole life of Lord Brahmaa),it means that creation process started at a particular time. So what before that? This contradicts the fact that the creation process is without any beginning and end.

Comment: The best somebody told me earlier is that Lord Brahma is describing only about some selected important births and telling them in the chronological order even if they are not.

Comment: @LSSJBroly - "Creation process is without any beginning or end" - there is misconception. creation is cyclic. it has both beginning and end, but it keeps repeating forever.

Comment: Ohh!! @mar so you mean the creation process has started at some point and is repeating since then....

Comment: @LSSJBroly - there is confusion in definition of word 'creation'. let's say there is empty piece of land. on top you 'create' building. 10 years later, you destroy it. then u wait 10 years it is just empty land. again you create building. 10 years later destroy. 10 years wait. create. 10 years wait. destroy. 10 years wait. create. 10 years wait. destroy. this cycle of creation and destruction of building (aka universe) has been going on forever and will go on forever. there is no 'start' date before which there was no building forever.

Comment: Thank you @mar ji and I like the analogies you give to make things easier. 

Answer (score 0):

The only logic I can apply is. These are the point of perspective of higher beings viz tridevs from their owm calculation of time.

**Sri Shiva Purana 2.1:1:10.:**

> *15. Listen to the span of life of the deities—Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Hara. There shall not be any doubt in this respect.*
>
> *16. A thousand sets of the four-yuga periods constitute one day of Brahmā. The period of night is also similar. Further measurement of time is based on this calculation.*
>
> *17. Thirty such days (days and nights) constitute one month and twelve months, one year. The span of life of Brahmā is hundred such years.*
>
> *18. **One year of Brahmā constitutes one day of Viṣṇu. Viṣṇu lives for hundred years in his own calculation.***
>
> *19. **One year of Viṣṇu constitutes one day of Rudra. When a hundred year period passes, Rudra assumes the form of Nara (supreme Man).***
>
> *20. **He (Rudra) stays like that as long as the breath is retained by Sadāśiva. When He (Sadāsiva) exhales he (Rudra) merges into Śakti (Prakriti).***
>
> *21-22. In the case of all living beings, Brahmā, Viṣṇu, Hara, Gandharvas, serpents, Rākṣasas, etc., twenty one thousand six hundred respirations constitute the period of one day and one night, O foremost among Devas.*
>
> *23-24. Six respirations constitute the period of time one Pala. Sixty such Palas constitute one Ghaṭī. Sixty Ghaṭīs constitute one day and one night. (6 x 60 x 60 = 21600). **There is no limit to the number of respirations of Sadāśiva. Hence He is undecaying.***

Thus, everyone have their each sets of time cycle.

So, here to my understanding, Lord Brahma is saying he took 6 births from Lord Vishnu already and this is his 7th birth.

- 1 Brahma = 100 days of Vishnu.
- 6 Brahmas = 600 days of Vishnu.
- 1 month = 30 days.
- 6 Brahmas = 20 months of Vishnu.
- 7th Brahma's age = 51 years = 20 months + 1 month + 21 days of Vishnu.

Thus, we are in the 21st day of the 21st month (1 year and 9 months) of Lord Vishnu.

Similarly, we are in the
18th hour of the 2nd day of Lord Rudra. As for Bhagawan Sada Shiva, he might have just started inhaling.

Even **Sri Skanda Purana 7.1.7.10** also confirms this.:

> ***Shiva Said -***
>
> ***Six Brahmās have passed away. The present Prajāpati who is well-known as Śatānanda is the seventh one, O goddess.***

**Conclusion.:** It's the same Brahma who takes birth from Lord Vishnu in various ways and this is his 7th birth and we are in his 51st year.

Bdw, That's just my theory.

I hope this clarifies your queries.