# The verse which particularly says that it's the same Lord Brahma who takes birth from Lord Vishnu's navel everytime.?

Tags: scripture, brahma, rebirth, birth, verse

I saw a screenshot of a verse in Quora last year or so, in some answer or comment where Lord Vishnu says to Lord Brahma that *"It was you only who took birth from my navel last 7 times or so and it will you yourself who will take birth again."* It was something like that which i vaguely remember it. I don't remember from which scripture this verse is from.

So, I will really appreciate if someone provide me with this verse and its source.

**Note.:** I don't want useless answers or comments which says Brahma is a jiva, it is a post, next brahma is this snd that boa bla bla. As this unnecessary things are not et all related to my original question. Prd..

Edit.: I think when OP says something people should just listen and respect it instead of uttering baseless unnecessary things. But some people just don't understand such simple little things. May Bhagawan bless them. Prd..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a verse where Lord Brahma said what i have asked above. So, i am posting it as my answe,if there is another verse where plLord Vishnu said it then provide me with it.

**The Mahabharata, Book 12.: Santi Parva.: Section CCCXLVIII.:**

> ***As regards myself (Brahma), I have sprung through thy (Narayana's) Grace. From thee have I derived my birth. My first birth from thee, which is regarded sacred by all regenerate persons, was due to a fiat of thy Mind. My second birth in days of yore was from thy eyes. Through thy Grace, my third birth was from thy speech. My fourth birth. O puissant Lord, was from thy ears. My fifth birth, excellent in all respects, was from thy nose. O Lord, My sixth birth was, through thee, from an egg. This is my seventh birth. It has occurred, O Lord, within this Lotus, and it is meant to stimulate the intellect and desires of all the beings. At each Creation I take birth from thee as thy son, O thou that art divested of the three attributes. Indeed, O lotus-eyed one, I take birth as thy eldest son, made up of Sattwa the foremost of three attributes.***

|| Om Tat Sat ||