# If we are all Vishnu, where do the Thrimuurthulu live?

Tags: vishnu, belief, gods, moksha, universe

The entire universe came into formation from one god - Lord Vishnu. Then how can we describe the REALM in which all the other gods like Brahma, Shiva, Indra live? Are they too a part of Lord Vishnu or separate entities?

Comment: Not all agree, entire universe came from Vishnu. See [How were the Trimurthi born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/237/3500)

Answer (score 2):

**How can we describe the REALM in which all the other gods like Brahma, Shiva, Indra live?**

The Trimurthis do exists in all this Universe /space- time, It is difficult to explain the nature of their existence, and their true potentialities since they belong to the very highest realms of creation.

So Trimurty’s remain in their real aspect as pure energies and consciousness with dimensions / domains beyond our imagination, beyond thought, beyond sense perception, beyond mind and speech, Only handful of yogis  and Rushies envisioned them and their abode’s in deep meditation.

---

**Are they too a part of Lord Vishnu or separate entities?**

I am herewith presenting some verses which are pointing at your question. Here are they -

There is a interesting story In Shreemad Bhagvatam related to your enquiry. This story is a of Shree Atri Rushi  and Anusuya . When Brahmadeva ordered Atri rushi to beget children , he performed great Tapasya (severe austerities) . And while doing that he was meditating on the supreme Creator of this universe.

> शरणं तं प्रपद्येSहं य एव **जगदिश्वर**: |
>  प्रजामात्मसमां मह्यं
>   प्रयच्छत्विति चिन्तयन् ||20||
>
> śaraṇaṁ taṁ prapadye ’haṁ  ya eva jagad-īśvaraḥ|
>  prajām
>   ātma-samāṁ mahyaṁ prayacchatv iti cintayan ||
>
> He was thinking: **May the Lord of the universe, of whom I have taken
>   shelter,** kindly be pleased to offer me a son exactly like Him.[**SB
>   4.1.20**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/1/20)

While Atri Muni was engaged in these severe austerities, a blazing fire came out of his head by virtue of his breathing exercise, and that fire was seen by the three principal deities of the three worlds. 
That fire was perceived by the Supersoul, Viṣṇu, and thereby Lord Brahmā and Śiva also perceived it.

Then Atri rushi asked three of them O Lord Brahmā, Lord Viṣṇu and Lord Śiva, I beg to inquire whom of you three I have called by my prayer.?
The three great deities smiled, and they replied in the following sweet words.

> देव उवाच – Dev Uvacha
>
> यथा कृथस्ते सङ्कल्पो भाव्यं तेनैव नान्यथा |
>  सतसङ्कल्प्स्य ते
>   ब्रह्मन् यद्वै ध्यायति ते वयम् ||30||
>
> yathā kṛtas te saṅkalpo bhāvyaṁ tenaiva nānyathā
>  sat-saṅkalpasya
>   te brahman yad vai dhyāyati te vayam
>
> The three deities told Atri Muni: Dear brāhmaṇa, you are perfect in
>   your determination, and therefore as you have decided, so it will
>   happen; it will not happen otherwise. **We are all the same person
>   upon whom you were meditating,** and therefore we have all come to
>   you. [**SB 4.1.30**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/1/30)
>
> ---

We can see a very another similar verse in Shreemad Bhagvatam **Skanda Four –Chapter 7 –Verse 50.** Which is by Supreme creator himself.

> Shree Bhagvan Uvacha –
>
> अहं ब्रह्मा च शर्वच्श्र जगत: कारणं परम् |
>  आत्मेश्वर् उपद्रष्टा
>   स्वयंदृगविशेषण ||50||
>
> ahaṁ brahmā ca śarvaś ca jagataḥ kāraṇaṁ param 
>  ātmeśvara upadraṣṭā
>   svayan-dṛg aviśeṣaṇaḥ
>
> **Brahmā, Lord Śiva and I are the supreme cause of the material manifestation. I am the Supersoul, the self-sufficient
>   witness. But impersonally there is no difference between Brahmā, Lord
>   Śiva and Me.

These verses tells us  that at the highest level Trimurty’s  are the three aspects of the one and the same supreme Reality.

Your question is  whether these gods are part of  Lord Vishnu or separate entities, the answer can be in terms  both Yes and No., From human perspective they  are different because they perform different tasks, have qualities and energies that are different  widely from one another. And from high reality they are one and the same.

---

**Note** – <sub>It’s is not necessary that everybody should believe in their unity .There are different views regarding this topic among different school of thoughts OR Sects .This is my attempt to answer this  questions using verses. There are various ways and total freedom in Hinduism given by supreme god himself to understand the truth and through them to  know and to reach him.</sub>