# Does Moksha Dharma Parva contain this alleged quotation from it?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, krishna, creation

In an answer to the question

[How were the Trimurthi born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born/259#259)

The following material is quoted:
'

> As Krishna says in the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata, "The ancestors of civilization, and entities such as Shiva, were created by Me. They do not know of this because they are illusioned by My cosmic material energies."

the link given is broken.  instead,

https://gaudiya.redzambala.com/sahasranama/vishnu-sahasranama-by-baladeva-vidyabhushana.html

says

> Note: Shrila Baladeva Vidyabhushana quotes the following verses from Mahabharata, where Krishna explains that He is the source of all living
> beings.

> prajapatim ca rudram capy
> aham eva shrijami vai
> tau hi mam na vijanito
> mama maya-vimohitau

> "The patriarchs, Shiva and others are created by Me, though they do not know that are created by Me, because they are deluded by My illusory energy."*

It is alleged to be from the Moksha Dharma Parva of the Mahabharata- where can it be found there?

Comment: What do you mean by a genuine quote?

Comment: By the way, the original word used is Rudra not Shiva. There is a big difference.

Comment: Actually its Rudra... Not Shiva...

Answer (score 1):

this alleged citation from the Mahabharata was made in a comment to the question

[How were the Trimurthi born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born/259#259)

Actually the citation is from Varaha Purana, in the context of Vishnu explaining the power of his maya to the earth.

THE
VARAHA-PURANA
Translated and Annotated by
S. VENKITASUBRAMONIA IYER

MOTILAL BANARSIDASS PUBLISHERS
PRIVATE LIMITED • DELHI

pages 295-298

> 1. After listening to the actions to be performed in the six
>    seasons, Earth again asked Lord Narayana.
> 2. "You have explained the auspicious and sacred actions
>    to be performed, that indeed gladden your mind.
> 3. Knowing these from you, О Madhava, I have become
>    free from stain like the moon in autumn.
> 4. I am now eager to know another secret which you may
>    be pleased to enlighten me about, namely.
> 5. What is it that you speak of as my maya (illusory power);
>    what is its nature, О Visnu.
> 6. I wish to know this great secret, namely the meaning of
>    Maya"
> 7. Visnu, who is the very repository of maya, laughed a
>    little at this, and then told Earth:
> 8. "You ask this quite earnestly, but why do you ask this
>    since you see it yourself ?
> 9. But know this that even Rudra, Indra and Brahma have
>    not known me fully even now; then how can you, О Earth, know
>    my Maya ?
> 10. Where the clouds shower rain, there water accumulates,
>     but there are also places without any water. This is due
>     to my maya.
> 11. The moon wanes in one fortnight and waxes in the next,
>     and does not appear at all on new moon day. This is really due
>     to my maya
> 12. In winter/the water in the well is warm, but in summer
>     it is cool. This really is due to my maya.
> 13. The sun sets in the west and rises in the east the next
>     morning. This is due to my maya.
> 14. The generative fluid is in the female and the semen is
>     in the male. In the womb they combine to form a being. This
>     is due to my maya.

---

> 51. **I create Brahma and Rudra and hold them. But due
>     to the power of my may a they do not know it.**