# How many creation stories are there in Shastras?

Tags: scripture, puranas, upanishads

Unlike the Abrahamic religions which gives us an account of only one creation story in their holy scriptures, Hinduism on the other hand has more than one creation story.
How many such stories are there in total and in which Shastras? ...
And which creation story is the most popular or widely accepted among the hindus?

Comment: I don't think anyone would have counted them, but there are plenty of them. They are found in variety of text, including tantras. For e.g. see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45346/21353) story it comes from a tantra.

Comment: Unfortunately, your reference to there being only '1' creation story in Christianity is a flawed popular myth. In The book of genesis there are 2 (the story of Adam being 1, the story of Seth being 2). In the old testament there are several, the one most often occurring is Leviathan. In the Upanishads there are several. Unlike the Christian, there is no creation out of nothing, the word used in Sanskrit is 'sristhi' - projection. There are many different ways that the projection is described.

Comment: Too broad to answer